# Windows Phone ApplicationBar BackgroundColor property style XamlParseException

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, application-bar

I had a lot of pages in my application and I had decided to make a global ApplicationBar style in App.Resources:

```xml
<Style TargetType="shell:ApplicationBar">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#006699" />
</Style>
```

However, when I tried to start the app, VS gave me an error:

```
The property 'BackgroundColor' was not found in type 'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar'.
```

This isn't true - [ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.backgroundcolor%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, ApplicationBar properties cannot use `Binding` or styling the way you're trying, as it is not a silverlight control. Although you can put the `whole` applicationbar as a resource. Like so

```
<shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="MyAppBar" IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="#006699">
         <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/image.png" Text="image"  IsEnabled="True"/>  
</shell:ApplicationBar>
```

EDIT:
Or you could just put this in the resource if you want your application bar color to change.

```
<shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="MyAppBar" IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="#006699">
</shell:ApplicationBar>
```

And add buttons from code behind. although, I haven't come across a scenario where this would help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't solve my problem, because every ApplicationBar in my app has a different button and menu item set. If you are referring to the fact, that I can put all sets in one resource file - it will be somewhat easier to locate them, but amount of work in case I decide, for example, to change resource type of any property, won't be any smaller. Thanks for reminding, that it isn't a Silverlight control, though. It explains everything.

Comment: I agree it will be quite cumbersome. Added another option which, depending on your situation, might help.

Comment: Well, it is a universal solution, however my situation isn't so extreme :) I just was wondering, is there a WPF-way. Thanks.