# How to apply style to application bar globally?

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

I checked the Application bar but no style attribute is shown. I have about 10 pages that use an app bar so it would be ideal to set a style in the Application.Resources. Is it possible to apply a style to all application bars in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you have different application bars on different pages and you want to have a style which can be applied to all. Unfortunately, binding does not work with application bars. You may have to style all of them one by one. For more information:
[Windows Phone ApplicationBar BackgroundColor property style XamlParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278438/windows-phone-applicationbar-backgroundcolor-property-style-xamlparseexception)

Comment: Ok I see. I hope that changes in the future. Thanks for the quick response. I'll check your answer as accepted as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

You can pretty much do this with a abstract class which your pages inherit from.

```
public abstract class BasePage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public abstract bool UsingApplicationBar { get; }

        public Color ApplicationBarColor= Colors.Gray;

    public BasePage()
    {
        Loaded += BasePageLoaded;

    }

    private void BasePageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (UsingApplicationBar)
        {
            ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = ApplicationBarColor;
        }

    }
}
```