# How to change the application bar background color dynamically for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created an application bar through codes(in xaml.cs), but if i tried to change the background color of the app bar, it throws an error. I think the below codes is not correct for an app bar.

```
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8280067/81053

Answer (score 9):

The [BackgroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.backgroundcolor%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property type is *Color* and not *Brush*:

```
public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }
```

So, following should work:

```
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
```

PS. Most of the times, reading compile time error messages can give you a lot of clarity.